# Chrome not saving passwords (and not auto filling existing login/passwords)

Tags: google-chrome

I am little surprised but Google Chrome is not saving/showing passwords for certain sites (Facebook and Google to name a few). I remember it was saving this earlier, but somehow it is not.

What has caused this?

No sites are in the "Do not save password" list.

Comment: Have the sites disabled form auto-complete?

Comment: A client of mine was having the same issue, and it was fixed by letting Chrome update.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In Chrome's settings (navigate to `chrome://settings/` or choose *Settings* from the... menu?) make sure that you have both "**Enable Autofill to fill out web forms in a single click**" and "**Offer to save passwords I enter on the web**" are checked. These are under *Passwords and Forms* and you'll need to click the link to show advanced settings.

[image: Chrome Passwords and Forms settings]

Also check that you are signed into Chrome with the account that you intend on being signed in with and that the sync settings are correct. It could be some weird sync issue where it is saving them until you close and reopen the browser or somesuch.

If all else fails, re-installing Chrome couldn't hurt.

Comment: path to follow: `chrome://settings/passwords`

Comment: great for 2013, doesn't apply in 2019

Comment: And when this doesn't work?

Comment: @Madivad Works in 2020, though. Looks different, but the options are the same.

Comment: The settings now have a search to make finding this stuff super easy (i.e. search "autofill", click "Passwords", toggle "Offer to save passwords" and "Auto Sign-in")

Comment: Those settings are there, but occasionally it still doesn't work – that's when the answer from JessG helps.

Answer (score 101):

If the settings to store passwords are enabled, but it still doesn't work, removing the password database might help.

Here are steps:

- Quit Chrome.
- Go to the directory where Chrome stores its user-specific data, below your user home directory:

  - Mac: `~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome`
  - Linux: `~/.config/google-chrome`. Note that Chromium `snap` (default on Ubuntu 20.10 and earlier) is at `~/snap/chromium/common/chromium/Default/` however
  - Windows: `%UserProfile%\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data`
- From there, go into the directory called Default if you want to fix your main profile, or into  Profile 1 or Profile 2, etc., to fix one of your extra profiles.
- Delete the files "Login Data" and "Login Data-journal".
- Repeat for other profiles as necessary.

*Thanks to http://plasmasturm.org/log/chromepwstore/ for this successful fix.*

*update:*

This solution still works in 2019 and on kubuntu 18.04. Many comments below indicate other versions where it worked.

Comment: oh my god, this was the problem. So...: this solution still works in 2019 and work under kubuntu

Comment: This solution works in Windows in 2020!

Comment: Works on OSX still, early 2020

Comment: This solution works in Linux! Nice trick!

Comment: Worked in Fedora 31, spring 2020

Comment: Worked on Ubuntu 18.04 on 2020-04-04! Finally!

Comment: Worked! At last! Ubuntu 20.04. Chrome Version 81.0.4044.122 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: Thanks! Worked on Ubuntu 20.04 with Chrome 83 (google-chrome-stable)

Comment: After all steps you have to close your Chrome and open it again. (83.0.4103.61 (Official Build) (64-bit))

Comment: this works on ubuntu 16.0.4

Comment: Works on KDE Neon 5.19

Comment: no longer works...

Comment: Works on macOS Catalina with Chrome 85.

Comment: Worked even on Chromium and Ubuntu 20.04. Thank you.

Comment: Worked on Linux Mint 20

Comment: Thanks, worked on Ubuntu 20.04 and Chrome 86

Comment: Thanks, worked in MX Linux KDE!

Comment: Thanks a lot! Still works in 2020.

Comment: Worked for me too on arch (wouldn't work after changing the window manager)

Comment: In Ubuntu 20.4, with the Chromium snap package, the files to delete are under `~/snap/chromium/common/chromium/Default`.

Comment: I noticed that this started when I backed-up and moved my Linux home directory to the new computer. New computer had a different log-in password. I suspect that Chrome was using my OS log-in password to decrypt saved passwords and now, when the password have been changed, it no longer works?

Comment: Worked for me on ubuntu 20.04LTS.

Comment: After unexpected power shutdown, chromium stopped autofilling logins and passwords for my main (default) profile. This solution helped me.
Arch Linux, chromium 89.0.4389.114, kde.

Comment: This is indeed THE correct answer. Works for Chromium too which I am using in Linux and had failed to save and remember passwords to sites. No need for new profiles as  has been suggested.

Comment: Wow, surprised this did it, thank you! (Ubuntu 21.04, Chrome 93, 2021)

Comment: Worked! i3, Linux 5.11.0-40-generic.

Comment: Windows, 2022 - does not work

Comment: Works in 2022 on Mac BigSur 11.6.3 (20G415)

Comment: Worked on Ubuntu 22.04

Comment: worked on 22.04. Thanks a lot !!

Comment: works for macOS Monterrey

Comment: On Android Chrome I used 'Manage Space' and then 'Clear All Data'

Comment: Works for Ubuntu 23.04!

Answer (score 14):

I had this problem, but I found the solution.
With your username and password login to the site, then click the key icon at end of the address bar.

[image]

Comment: UI so intuitive, it's not. I tried everything and this was the key (no pun intended).

Comment: Thank you very much, this worked! But don't ask me why it is not consistent. On most sites it just works.

Comment: This worked for me! Thank you much! Admittedly I was initially confused by the wording. Any chance this answer could be edited to just say "Login to the site with your username and password, and then click the key icon at end of the address bar."?

Answer (score 7):

We have a local server to which I was trying to connect - "https://bowser.gruff.org/admin".

When I first connected, I left off most of the URL, just entering "bowser/admin", which worked (because of sufficiently satisfactory name resolution). However, I got a warning from Chrome (Chromium, actually) that warned that the https site was not secure; I just went into the Advanced settings and told Chrome to ignore the security warning, and was able to log in. But Chrome never prompted me to save my password.

After a couple of days of this, I came and found this site, and after trying other things unsuccessfully, reset my Chrome settings to the default ("Settings" / "Show advanced settings..." / "Reset settings"). Then when I reloaded my page, I again got the security error, and noticed the URL address bar had a red flag with https X'd out, and realized maybe Chrome is not saving passwords on insecure https sites.

So I put in the full URL of "https://bowser.gruff.org/admin", and this time Chrome offered to save my password.

Hopefully this info might help someone.

Comment: I also had a local site not offering to save passwords. I had to install the (self-generated) certificate to work correctly.

Answer (score 6):

Using a clean new profile was the only way that fixed this problem for me:

1. Go to settings via the following URL:

   ```
   chrome://settings
   ```
2. Click on the *Add person...* button to add a new profile

   ```
   chrome://settings/createProfile
   ```
3. Make this new Chrome profile your default browser to navigate the web

Comment: If you are using a signed in profile you will need to sign out of it first before creating the new profile.

Answer (score 4):

I had "Enable Autofill" and "Offer to save passwords" checked.  Also, I didn't see any sites in my "Never saved".  What fixed it for me was resetting my settings to the default (there is a button on the bottom of the Settings page, in the advanced section).

Comment: Do a backup before trying this: `cp -a $HOME/.config/google-chrome $HOME/.config/google-chrome_OLD`.

Answer (score 3):

None of these suggestions worked for me. I found a helpful link in the Chrome forum that suggests that this happens because your Chrome profile can become corrupted. Here are the steps to take to create a new profile and get your password saving working again:

https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/142059?hl=en

Following these steps also caused my previously saved passwords to come back!

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately I've got the same problem even though I checked remember my password and etc.

But this worked for me so I share it with you, go to:
chrome://settings/content

and check the recommended option for cookies(something with "allow to save locally", I don't remember what it exactly was) and click OK. That helped me.

Answer (score 1):

Just make sure that you did not save the password for the same domain with a different port!

- Chrome is ignoring the port when checking the URL to save or not save.
- But when fill the fields it cares about the port.

I think this is a Bug in Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

This is a 'security' feature of Chrome profiles. Chrome does not offer to store passwords for Google (and some other) accounts if you have added your profile to Chrome.

The solution is to:

1. Remove yourself (your profile) from Chrome
2. Log in to Gmail, FB etc. Chrome will now offer to store the
   passwords.
3. Add your profile back into Chrome.

Comment: To clarify, https://accounts.google.com/signin is blocked on the password manager. Disabling the "Allow Chrome sign-in" setting might fix it too. - ps, why the heck is this getting flagged as spam

Comment: @RayFoss what exactly is getting flagged as spam? I hope the answer is not what I think it is.

Answer (score 0):

Here are few things you can try doing.

- Try deleting existing saved passwords. May be Chrome has a limit on the number of saved passwords.
- Try re-installing the Google Chrome. It might be a bug
- Updating Google Chrome to most recent version

Comment: 1) it doesn't seem to be a limit—I just deleted a few dozen passwords, and a site that used to store 3 username/password combos for me only stores 1 now.
2) )One shouldn't need to update Chrome, as it generally updates itself

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with my site. It appeared that email and password input of sign in form had no name attributes. When I added them and refresh page chrome showed me "save password" popup at the same moment

Answer (score 0):

https://www.google.com/settings/chrome/sync

Reset Sync

While you are signed out you can save passwords.

Comment: Clicking on your link takes me to a Google sign-in page, so the link adds no value.  The rest of the answer is cryptic.  Can you expand your answer and include the essential information from the link?

Answer (score 0):

I went to chrome://settings/content and clicked all cookie and site data.
deleted all cookies and chrome started working correctly again.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to allowing Google to remember passwords in the advanced settings, you also have to allow google to set cookies, otherwise google will continue to ask you to login when you exit and go back in.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Incognito mode Chrome won't prompt to save your passwords either (even if you have "Offer to save passwords" enabled).

Tested using Google Chrome v73.0.3683.103.

Answer (score 0):

I've had this issue at one of our clients where they are on a terminal server and login with their usernames with their profiles. My issue was that the autofil usernames were updating, but the passwords were not, and the "key" symbol on the top right was missing so they could not save their passwords.

I found a fix : this is related to the chrome temp profile :
Hit run and navigate to `%appdata%` - this will get you to your appdata path on the profile. 
in our case its not a roaming profile so was only on the C drive Example:
`C:\Users\**username**\AppData\Roaming`

Point is, to rename 2 folders in appdata, one in Roaming, one in local :

`C:\Users\R1eger\AppData\Roaming\Google\Chrome` - rename `User Data` folder

`C:\Users\R1eger\AppData\local\Google\Chrome` - rename `User Data` folder

Restart Chrome, and it will ask you to login once again.
Once logged in, it started to ask the passwords again

Hope this helps someone

Answer (score 0):

I answer from a Linux perspective (so, I'm not able to say what the Windows-equivalent of what I'm going to say is). I also assume that, when one asks «Why is Google Chrome no longer saving passwords?», what one really wants to know (which is the reason why I landed on this page) is why Chrome, even if it apparently keeps on saving login data (for example: you log in to your Google account, fill in your data, and Chrome asks you «Do you want me to save your login data?»; you answer YES; and when, tomorrow, you try to log in again, you find that your data are gone), actually doesn't save them any more.

I add that «from a Linux perspective» actually means «a KUbuntu 19.10 perspective»: indeed, I haven't found any such problem in Fedora, nor in openSUSE, nor in Arch.

1. apply the suggestion originally made by [JessG](https://superuser.com/users/908521/jessg) [here](https://superuser.com/a/1325741/1170204). Then
2. [**very important**] navigate to '/home/user/.local/share/kwalletd/' and
3. delete your 'kwallet.kwl' file.

Reopen Chrome. On start-up, it will activate your KWallet application, which will prompt you for a password in order to store your login secrets privately. Do whatever you like, here: if you usually put a password in there, do it; or, leave it blank in order to avoid the hassle of having KWallet ask you for your password every time you open Chrome. But, at any rate, what you need to rebuild is your 'kwallet.kwl' file.

Then, try again to log in to Google, or Facebook, or whatever. The usual procedure will start: but, this time, your login data should be kept where they have to, and you should be able to find them again the next time you'll need to use them.

Hope this helps...

P.S.: of course, my little "fix" works also for Chromium, Opera, Vivaldi, as well as any other Chromium-based browser which needs to talk with the KWallet demon in order to store login secrets...

P.S.2 (January 24, 2022): I add that my "fix" still works PERFECTLY even with KUbuntu 21.10 and Chrome 97.0.4692.99 (64-bit)...

Answer (score -1):

Open Internet Explorer and go to your site. When asked to save the password in IE, say 'Yes'. Now go back to Chrome and go to 'settings', now import saved passwords from IE.

Comment: Please do not post all in capitals

Comment: Question is about Chrome

Comment: @vaichidrewar You didn't read the whole answer. It was about Chrome, but granted, a very round about way of solving the problem.

Answer (score -1):

Besides checking all the recommended chrome settings, i.e. Autofill-ON, Offer to save passwords-ON, as well as setting chrome://flags/#PasswordForceSaving -ON be sure to DELETE (click 'x') the 'Never Saved' list at the bottom of chrome://settings/passwords/.
If you have been trying to get a particular site to save your password, and the site tab is still up, delete the tab and restart Chrome and do a fresh browse to that site. Also, I didn't see it documented but if you don't get the 'Save Password' pop-up immediately after all those setting are ON and you have the chrome://flags/#PasswordForceSaving ON then right mouse click (win) after you have entered your password and while the cursor is still in the password box and you should see a pop-up menu with 'Save password' at the top which you should click.
I had to do all this a couple of times on some Gov of Canada sites to fix my Not Saving Password problem.

Answer (score -2):

"Open Internet Explorer or Firefox and go to your site. When asked to save the password in IE or Firefox, say 'Yes'. Now go back to Chrome and go to 'settings', now import saved passwords from IE or Firefox" worked for me. Thanks Alex Tvp Storr