# Chrome doesn't remember browser sessions after restart

Tags: linux, ubuntu, google-chrome, kubuntu, cinnamon

When I restart my computer and open Chrome again, my tabs from my previous session are reopened. However, most websites (Gmail, GitHub, Twitter/Tweetdeck, StackExchange) ask me to login again.

I'm using different user profiles and I've the same problem with all of them.

I think the problem started after updating to Chrome 53, but I'm not 100% sure that's the case and even if so, if that's a coincidence or not.

When I look at the developer console, the cookies are still there. On some websites, I'm still logged in.

How can I find out what's going wrong?

**Update**:
I've reinstalled Chrome (`apt purge`, `rm -rf ~/.config/google-chrome` and `apt install`) and now it's asking me to login again (enter my password and two-factor auth) on my Chrome profile every time I <del>reboot</del> restart Chrome. There is a small warning sign on my profile name (right top).

[image]

The settings page says 'Account sign-in details are out of date.'
[image]

**Update 2**: I even have this problem after closing Chrome and restarting it.

Comment: Try the suggestions on [this post](http://superuser.com/questions/573602/google-chrome-not-saving-passwords-and-not-auto-filling-existing-login-password).

Comment: @harrymc Nope, that's another problem. My browser still auto completes, but I should not get a login form in the first place (because I should be still logged in after a reboot).

Comment: Some of the suggestions in my link above were general. For example, reset settings, try another [profile](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/142059?hl=en), re-install Chrome after total cleanup. I suppose you are using https addresses for the websites.

Answer (score 10):

### Solution

To fix this issue you need to unlock your keyring **before** launching chrome.

1. Disconnect your Google account; go to `chrome://settings` click
   `Disconnect your Google Account...` check the box to clear local
   Chrome data, sign out and then close Chrome.
2. Launch seahorse by typing `seahorse` into the terminal or open it from `Menu`>`Passwords and Keys`.
3. In `Default keyring` delete `Chrome Safe Storage` and any `accounts.google.com` enteries.
4. Unlock the `Default Keyring` and `Login` by right clicking and clicking `Unlock`
5. Launch Chrome, go to `chrome://settings` and click `Sign in to Chrome`

Hopefully this fixes your problem, I recently installed Linux Mint and this worked for me, I don't fully understand why but it seems Chrome does not wait for the keyring to unlock and this results in chrome not being signed in.

### Reproduce This Issue

Steps to reproduce this issue:

1. Install Linux (mint or otherwise) with cinnamon (on a VM or otherwise)
2. Install Chrome and sign in
3. Reboot
4. Ensure Keyrings are locked - go to `Passwords and Keys` and lock all Keyrings
5. Open chrome - you will be prompted to unlock the Keyring and sign in will fail

Comment: Worked for Ubuntu 18.04. It took me a couple tries to be disciplined enough to really reproduce the steps properly.

Answer (score 8):

Maybe chrome is automatically clearing your cookies when you reboot.

Go to `chrome://settings/content` and under "Cookies" see if "Keep local data only until you quit your browser" is selected (like below).

[image: Keep local data only until you quit your browser]

If yes, then change it to "Allow local data to be set (recommended)", like so...

[image: Allow local data to be set]

Also, check if there are any Cookie exceptions under `chrome://settings/contentExceptions#cookies` [especially since you say 'On some websites, I'm still logged in.']

For example,

[image: Cookie Exception]

Try changing Behaviour from "Clear on exit" to "Allow"

Comment: Unfortunately, all settings are already like this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: Disconnect your google account in settings, close Chrome, re-open and sign-in, under advanced sync settings change from "sync everything" to "choose what to sync" and temporarily uncheck any of the boxes, click OK, change back to "sync everything" and ensure all boxes are checked and click OK.

Answer (score 0):

[This answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/823763/325443) helped me to solve similar problem. The solution is following:

> 1. Go to Ubuntu `System Settings` -> [Online Accounts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I57Li.png)
> 2. Add your Google account there
> 3. Turn on [the switcher](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hLkBO.png) (not sure if it is necessary though)
> 4. Go to Chrome browser and login there again
> 5. Close the browser window
>
> **Note**: you must prevent chrome processes from running after closing the window. To do this go to Chrome `Settings` > `Advanced settings`
>   (at the bottom) > Uncheck `Continue running background apps when
>   Google Chrome is closed`

Comment: The permissions that GNOME is asking for there are truly excessive. I'm not willing to grant them access to sending emails, all my data, etc.

Answer (score 0):

From Chrome **Menu** go to **Settings**  Check **Continue where you left off** under **On startup**

Also you can install the [Session Buddy](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/session-buddy/edacconmaakjimmfgnblocblbcdcpbko) extension to manage your browser sessions

Answer (score 0):

The solution with **unlocking keyrings** doesn't help if you use **automatic login** to the OS. Because after reboot the Default Keyring is locked again.

What actually helped me in this situation is **removing a master password for keyring**. Of course this is less secure, but if you use an auto login (like me), then I guess there's no worry for your files/passwords/etc.

Steps to do:

1. Close Chrome (no need to sign out from your profile).
2. Delete all keyrings of current user in seahorse app ("Default keyring", "Login", etc.), or using terminal: `rm ~/.local/share/keyrings/*.keyring`
3. The next time when you're being prompted for a keyring password, leave the password field blank (simply click *Continue* and then again *Continue*, thus agreeing to unsafe storage). That disables the keyring password for good.
4. Open Chrome, sign in to your account again. Don't forget to click "Advanced sync settings" button on the settings page, and check if there's a need for your passphrase.
5. (optional) Before testing whether this solution worked I was waiting until Chrome synced all my settings. I knew it finished when my HDD stopped making noise and HDD led stopped blinking.

Here's where I found this solution: https://sites.google.com/site/easylinuxtipsproject/tips#TOC-Disable-the-keyring-password

Comment: In Ubuntu 18.04, I have automatic login enabled but peter's solution (https://superuser.com/a/1141758/457084) worked for me. After you manually unlock before opening Chrome, you will be prompted to unlock your keyring but it appears that Chrome waits for the unlock to happen...